# How did anyone know Charles Kane's last words?

Tags: plot-explanation, citizen-kane

In the film "Citizen Kane", the entire plot revolves around a journalist attempting to find out the meaning of a billionaire's last words... "Rose Bud". However, at the beginning of the film - the event that sets the plot in motion - Kane collapses, drops the snow-globe he's holding, utters "Rose Bud" with his last breath, and then the nurse walks in to find him dead.

**Considering that Kane was alone when the words were uttered, how does anyone know that he said them?**

Comment: But he wasn't alone, the butler was in the room (we just don't see him). He explicitly *says* he was there and heard him say it. [BTW, I don't think you need to mark that as a spoiler, it happens in the beginning of the movie.]

Comment: @Walt Seems like an answer to me.

Comment: Well, I don't know if it's enough; maybe the OP is already aware of this and disagrees.

Comment: @Omegacron Sorry, it slipped my mind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### He wasn't alone.

The butler Raymond was there and heard him...but he wasn't shown on screen.

[**Script**](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/citizenkane.html)

> "That "Rosebud" - that don't mean anything.  **I heard him say it.** He just said "Rosebud" and then he dropped that glass ball and it broke on the floor.
>
> "He didn't say anything about that, so I knew he was dead - He said all kind of things I couldn't make out.  But I knew how to take care of him."